# Gparted cannot enlarge my Ubuntu partition although I have some unallocated space on the drive

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to enlarge the home partition on Ubuntu. When I click on <kbd>resize</kbd> in GParted, it can't be done even though I have 100 GB of unallocated space:

[image: GParted screenshot]

Comment: Did you boot from USB or CD? `gparted` cannot manipulate mounted partitions.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  You haven't provided much info (such as the error message you get, or specifics of your issue), but my guess is you are trying to re-size an 'in-use' partition which can only be done in very limited circumstances (eg. types of file-systems).  You need to unmount it, or use a 'live' system (that won't have it mounted)

Comment: please look my image

Comment: Your unallocated space is not next to the partition you want to enlarge; hence you would need to move the partition in the way to the 'top' of the unallocated space; putting the space between the 'moved' partition & your home partition, then it would expand.  This move may, if the partition is used in booting, create issues for booting whatever is/was on that (*ntfs msftdata*) partition but you can't see that on the picture. Backup first regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can only resize to adjacent unallocated space, so you would need to shrink sda5 or sda7 first (making sure to shrink in the right direction).
You could expand sda5 into the unallocated space, then shrink it from the right hand side in order to utilise the full unallocated space.

Comment: Edited to that effect.